# Read file buffer treats archives (zip, jar, etc) as directory and throws IOException

Tags: java-11, zip, ioexception, bytebuffer

I have a requirement to break large files into 2MB slices for transport across a bridge. The following block of code works for all file types except archives (zip, jar, etc), for which it throws an IOException, the message of which is "Is a directory".

```
try (FileChannel fileChannel = FileChannel.open(fullpath); WriteStream writeStream = channel.connect().orElseThrow()) {
    byte[] bytes = origFileName.getBytes();
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(maxsize - 10);

    buffer.putChar('M');
    buffer.put(bytes);
    buffer.flip();
    writeStream.write(buffer);

    while (fileChannel.position() < fileChannel.size()) {
        buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(maxsize - 10);
        buffer.putChar('D');
        fileChannel.read(buffer);
        buffer.flip();
        writeStream.write(buffer);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    LOG.error("IO exception " + e.getMessage() + ", " + origFileName, e);
}
```

The error in the log is:

```
IO exception Is a dir, file.zip
```

The error is thrown by the statement 'fileChannel.read(buffer)'. Any help you can give me in determining how to fix this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: That’s a weird, highly unlikely behavior. Plus, there is no class named `WriteStream` in the standard Java API. So, it’s worth adding more information about the actual environment. As a side note, allocating a new buffer for every step, is unnecessary and inefficient.

Comment: Are you sure `file.zip` isn't _actually_ a directory?

Comment: WriteStream is a custom class that writes to a BlockingQueue. And file.zip is NOT a directory...it is a common zip file.

Comment: In my experience, IOException gives the worst error message

Comment: Well, if file.zip is not a directory, I don't know what the cause is. I can't reproduce the issue. I can read a zip file using fileChannel.read in exactly the same way you're doing. Can you actually read file.zip in some other way, e.g. open it in an editor (even if it would obviously display gibberish)?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out an upstream process is converting the zip file into a directory. Please don't waste any more time on this question. I'm sorry I didn't better research the situation before posting.

Comment: In that case, you can delete the question. Glad you solved it.